# How to display data in listview from sqlite database in android

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    createDatabase();
    c = db.rawQuery(fetch,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        name =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number"));
        //Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,id + name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        from = new String[]{id, name, number};
        to = new int[]{R.id.label, R.id.numberq, R.id.num};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.layout,c,from,to,0);
    }
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
protected void createDatabase(){
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("PersonDB",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR, number VARCHAR);");

}
```

> I am trying to show data in list view but it is showing the Exception:"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        createDatabase();
        c = db.rawQuery(fetch,null);


            String[] from = new String[]{"_id","name","number"};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.label, R.id.numberq, R.id.num};
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.layout,c,from,to,0);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    protected void createDatabase(){
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("PersonDB",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR, number VARCHAR);");

    }
```

Comment: i started with the "id" thing because of the exception i changed it. The exception is same iin both cases.

Comment: and it is letting me retrieve the data if i am not using adapter i.e one record at a time.

Comment: uninstalling it doesn't work. Still showing the same exception.

Comment: in the String[] from... you have to specify column name not column value

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out change both `id` names to either `id` or `_id`

In addition, with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` you don't need to loop through the Cursor yourself, an adapter does this work for you.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(...);
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
        R.layout.layout, 
        cursor, 
        new String[]{"id", "name", "number"}, 
        new int[]{R.id.label, R.id.numberq, R.id.num});

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this in your code:

```
    protected void createDatabase(){
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("PersonDB",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR, number VARCHAR);");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

by

```
id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The column name of id in the table is **id** and **not** **_id**.
as seen in this line:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR, number VARCHAR);");
```

So, replace

```
id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

with

```
id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
```